# Can I edit standard wiki properties? (eg. Created By) How?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, wiki, properties

The question says it all: I am looking for a way to edit the standard wiki properties, mainly Modified By and Created By. I did a massive load of the wiki database at once through a program, but that makes me the standard creator and modifier. So for some documents I would like to change that manually.

I am not a SharePoint Online Global Administrator and can't be/get the rights for this.

Comment: You can use Powershell for that. Please tag your SharePoint version.

Answer (score 1):

Use this article to find about how to use PowerShell with SharePoint online.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161362(v=office.15).aspx

Once this is done, you can use below to change the `ModifiedBy` etc

```
$web=get-SPWeb "You Web URL"
//Get a new object called $web to pick site
$list=$web.Lists["Your List"]
$replacedUser =$web.EnsureUser("domainName\Account")
foreach($item in $list.Items)       
{        
   $item["Author"] = $replacedUser   
   $item["Editor"] = $replacedUser   
   $item.update()        
}        
$web.Update()        
$web.dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. I read up on the website you provided, but as expected I can not do this due to insufficient priviliges on our SharePoint environment: "To run the SharePoint Online Management Shell cmdlets, you have to be a SharePoint Online global administrator." I will add this to my question. Any other ideas you might have?

Comment: You can use CSOM (using .net) or JSOM (using javascript). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460431/sharepoint-client-object-model-setting-modifiedby-field